# how to process a jsp page with javascript and insert to main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i am trying to process a jsp page via ajax request and insert it into the main page like this.

> $.get('link to page', function(data) {
>                         $('#formContainer').html(data);
>                       });

in my jsp page that i am getting back from the server there is javascript code that i want to include with the html and will handle the form events (i have many forms and each one has a different functionality)

it seems that the javascript code isn't added to the page with the html code.

Any way to do to what i want?

thanks.

Comment: not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get()` will strip out `script` tags ( see docs);

You can use `load()` which will honor script. You need to  place script after the html it affects since `document.ready` has already occurred in the main page.

```
$('#formContainer').load('link to page')
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Docs explain script execution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you've noticed, `<script>` tags are not executed when you put them into `.html()`.  The only solution I found was to loop through the container, find all the script tags, and execute them by hand.

**edit:** charlietfl has a superior solution (of which I was previously ignorant).  I will leave this post here for anyone who cannot use that solution.